# How can I implement a scrollview in my RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

Please I have a RelativeLayout and I have a section in my Layout I would like to make scrollable, this selection below. Please kindly answer using my full code. thank you.

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layouts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_note"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

This is the full code below:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/rl"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/color12" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <include layout="@layout/menu_layout" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/menu_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/menus" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layouts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_note"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_notes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblDate"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#222222"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTime"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTotal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#222222"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />
 </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/menu_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/attach_view"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/attachment_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/aImage"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Attachment"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#222222" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/aImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email_attachment" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bot_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/attach_view"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lblRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tool_left"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lblLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tool_right"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_text_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            layout="@layout/tool_text_button_layout"
            android:padding="13dp" />

        <!--
         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tool_type_text" />
        -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tool_thumbs" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_sync"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sync"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_attachment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email_attachment_small"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_italics"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_italics"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_underline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_underline"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_mode"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/menus"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:divider="#ffffff"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:visibility="gone" >
  </ListView>

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/attach_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
            android:text="Add Image"
            android:textColor="#222222" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Audio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
            android:text="Add Audio"
            android:textColor="#222222" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
            android:text="Add Video"
            android:textColor="#222222" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="#222222"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:width="100dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btncancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:textColor="#222222"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:width="100dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you read about "ScrollView"? Just try putting the contents your framelayout inside a scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some `layout` (linear/relative) in the `scrollView` in place you needed and inside this `layout` put your `frameLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `<ScrollView>` around the elements you want to be scrolled. If I understood you right, this is this fragment:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layouts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layouts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```